# When do I need to register a Bitly app?

Tags: ios, twitter, oauth, url-shortener

I want to use Bitly in my iOS app to shorten URLs on behalf of users when posting to Twitter.

Bitly basic account provides an API key that can be used for this purpose.

But then they also offer to register an OAth app seemingly for same purpose.

So when would I need to register an app for this purpose vs. just using the API key from a "regular" Bitly account?

Answer (score 0):

If you skip OAuth 2 you have access to only a subset of the APIs.

In their documentation they specify which APIs require OAuth 2. For example: [user metrics](http://dev.bitly.com/user_metrics.html), and many of the [link metric](http://dev.bitly.com/link_metrics.html) APIs.